# Elasticsearch nested filter query

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's an example of my json document I'm trying to create a query against. The "params" field is mapped as "nested".

```
{
   "images": [
      {
         "name": "1907183375555f7c44126f23.67610475.png"
      },
      {
         "name": "5693836375575c567764bc2.87695507.png"
      }
   ],
   "sku": "MYSKU",
   "class": "some_class",
   "params": [
      {
         "name": "item1",
         "value": "item1value"
      },
      {
         "name": "item2",
         "value": "item2value"
      },
      {
         "name": "item3",
         "value": "item3value"
      },
      {
         "name": "item4",
         "value": "item4value"
      },
      {
         "name": "item5",
         "value": "item5value"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I create a filtered query that will search on the sku, class, and nested params? E.g. in pseudocode, I would have a "bool" "must" on the sku and class, and then a "nested" "filter" "bool" "must" on each of the params that make up the document.  At https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html I can see how one would use nested on a document where each nested field was a unique field name, but in my document each array element has "name" and "value".

Seems like this should be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it (for example):

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "class": "some_class"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "sku": "MYSKU1"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "params",
                        "filter": {
                           "term": {
                              "params.name": "item1"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "params",
                        "filter": {
                           "term": {
                              "params.name": "item3"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that there are separate `nested` filter clauses for each nested doc that you want to match (I only included two, but you could include as many as you want); if instead we used a `bool` inside a single `nested` clause, with a bunch of filters inside the inner `bool`, ES would try to find a single nested doc that matched all the supplied filters. This way we are telling ES that the `nested` filters don't have to all apply to the same nested document.

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/26552d6a8a285c7715b0ac4feab08bd283971664

Comment: Sloan, thanks for the answer. Will you please update your answer regarding "...find a single nested doc that matched all the supplied filters"? That is what I want to do. When I run my query, all of the nested params including params.name and params.value must match. The nested params will always be unique to a single document. Will the present separated nested params query do this? It seems like it will, but your comments talk about a bool inside a single nested clause, which your example query is not using. Anyways thanks and please clarify.

Comment: The document you posted has a list of name-value pairs; each name-value pair is in a separate child document. The query I posted will return a parent document that has one child document containing the name `"item1`"` and another child document containing the name `"item3"`. Given the document that you posted, the query I posted makes sense, and will return the document you posted. There's no way a single nested doc could match both nested filters, because it can only have one name. Make sense?